# Continuity of $\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}$ and its integral

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

While studying the function $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}$ I had a doubt about its continuity.

The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, so since $f$ is the ratio of the continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ $\cos x$ and the function $e^{1/x}+1$ which is continuous where it is defined I suppose that $f$ is continuous for every $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

The point is that I'm not sure how to approach $x=0$, since
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=0$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=1$$
So they are different, but I can't say that they differ from $f(0)$ since $f(0)$ doesn't even exist.

So I tend to tell that $f$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

And about its integral if $a<0<b$
$$\int_a^b \frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1}\text{d}x$$
Since $f$ is not defined at $x=0$ I have to split it like this
$$\int_a^0 \frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1} \text{d}x+\int_0^b \frac{\cos x}{e^{1/x}+1} \text{d}x$$
Or it is okay to leave it in one integral from $a$ to $b$? It is not improper since $f$ is limited around $0$. I have some doubts about this kind of integrals (when there is a point where the function is not defined but it is continuous in its domain), can someone tell me a general approach to them? Thanks.

Comment: You can set the value of $f(0)$ anything, it won't change the value of the integral. It will make $f$ integrable on $[a, b]$, even if $0 \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$ f$ is defined and continuous at $ (-\infty,0)\cup (0,+\infty)$.

both improper integrals $$\int_a^0f \text{ and } \int_0^bf$$
are convergent since $ f $ has limits on the right and on the left of $ x=0$.

On the other If we add the condition $$f(0)=0$$

then, $ f $ is Riemann integrable at $[a,0] $ and $ [0,b]$. It is therefore integrable at $ [a,b]$.

$F: x \mapsto \int_a^xf +\int_x^bf$ is continuous at $[a,b]$.
then
$$F(0)=\lim_{0^-}\int_a^xf+\lim_{0^+}\int_x^bf$$